# Finding the basis of the transpose of a q-ary lattice

Tags: lattice-crypto

Given $q$ and a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m}$, the $q$-ary lattice is defined as 
$$\Lambda(A)=\{x \in \mathbb{Z}^m:Ax=0 \bmod q\} $$
An instance of a q-ary lattice and its short basis is computed in [Generating short basis for hard random lattices](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/521.pdf). Once the short basis $T_A$ for $\Lambda(A)$ is given, computing the short vector $s$ in $\Lambda
(A)$ is given in [SamplePre algorithm](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/432.pdf).

Is it possible to find a short basis for $\Lambda(A^T)$, if we are given a short basis of $ \Lambda(A)$?

Basically I want to find the short vector $s^\prime$ such that $A^Ts^\prime=0 \bmod q$.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that such a short (nonzero) vector $s’$ exists, for a uniformly random $A$ and typical dimensions $m \gg n$.

Answer (score 4):

If $n<m$ then for almost all matrices $A$ the columns of $A^T$ will be linearly independent and in that case $\Lambda(A^T)$ is the lattice generated by the basis  $qI$ (which is the shortest possible basis for this lattice).

Comment: The basis would not be $qI$ because that does not include the columns of $A^T$.

Comment: The notations are confusing, but the question asks about the kernel lattice of $A^T$, so I don't see why that lattice should include the columns of $A^T$.